# AWK: How to increment values in a column by one

Tags: awk

In a previous question I asked how to decrement the value of all entries in a column by 1

The (correct) answer was
awk '{ $7--; print $0 }', where $7 means the 7th column

What would an analogous answer for INCREMENTING column values be?

Thanks so much

Christian

Comment: And to anticipate a future question: `awk '{ $7+=2; print $0 }'` will increment by two and `awk '{ $7*=3; print $0 }'` will triple it and `awk '{ $7/=4; print $0 }'` will quarter it.

Comment: Can't forget exponentiation! (They're the only math operator you missed, Dennis!) `awk '{ $7^=3 } 1'` will cube the column.

Answer (score 2):

Use `++` instead of `--`.